# cant find the matching array of object search by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i used a custom hook and i want to show a single item which is matched by particular id,i tried multiple method but didnt work.here is my code :

const SingleServiceDetail = () => {

```
const {idOfService} = useParams();
const [data] = useCustom();

const singleItem = data.find(element =>element._id === idOfService);
console.log(singleItem);
return (
    <div>
        <h2>You have Choosed :{idOfService}</h2>
        {/* <p>{singleItem.name}</p> */}
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: If you try to `console.log(data)` do you get the array of data ?
If yes does the element._id of the data has the same format as the idOfService ?

Comment: What does `console.log` print? Does it print the element there?

Comment: yes the problem caused for not matching the formet..it solved ..i got a new problem now.after reloading that page it become blank ..and if i run console.log(singleItem) it showing undefined twice then showing the searched array...it caused the reloading problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly `idOfService` from useParams is a string and `element._id` is a number.

Try with double equal it will type coerce and check the id.

```
const singleItem = data.find(element => element._id == idOfService);
```

else change the `idOfService` to number

```
const singleItem = data.find(element => element._id === +idOfService);
```

Comment: it worked thanks..can u do me one more favour ..after reloading that page it become blank ..and if i run console.log(singleItem)  it showing undefined twice then showing the searched array...it caused the reloading problem

Comment: it won't cause the reloading problem, check your router there might be some other issue.